# MS Reporting and TextBox LineHeight

Tags: reporting-services, textbox

I am using local reports (RDLC) in my app and I seem to have a problem getting the desired line height in text boxes - setting the `LineHeight` property of any TextBox is not doing anything. I set it to 5pt, 10pt, 5cm, 20cm - I just does not work. So, the question is - what am I doing wrong? Is this just another *feature* of reporting? Do I need to perform some kind of a ritual dance around it to make it work?

Comment: Are you referring to textboxes inside the details area?

Comment: Umm, there's just one type of textboxes to my knowledge - you just add them from the toolbox or using right-click -> insert -> textbox.

Comment: Well you can add a textbox manually and throw it anywhere on the report  - header, footer, detail. If you drag fields into a tablix or use the report wizaard, that automatically creates textboxes in the details section. Regardless, is this a textbox in the details area?

Comment: It does not matter where the textbox is (let it be just a textbox in the main body) - the problem is that in any case LineHeight property of the textbox does not do anything.